# Zeroization of sensitive data in Functional Programming Languages

Tags: memory, sensitive-data-exposure

Concerning the very familiar (and sensible) security practice of Zeroizing sensitive data from memory after you're finished with it, such as Cryptographic keys, passwords, etc, I was pondering how you can achieve that task when programming in a FP Language such as Erlang/Haskell and the likes.

Especially in something like Erlang, which may be running thousands of processes under a single OS process (the Erlang VM) I was thinking it would be quite bad if due to an error a crash dump is generated that may contain sensitive data which wasn't properly zeroized, from all those processes that crashed together with the VM.

The problem of course is that in such languages, once a variable gets assigned, you are not allowed to change its value. So far I see only two ways out of this situation:

1. In a typed FP language, you can have an option for the type that says something like "Sensitive" and then the GC can take care to Zeroize the value before it frees the space allocated to it.
2. You can have some kind of an "unbind" semantics where you explicitly unbind a variable in a way that also cleanses its content. Of course, you should not be allowed to use the same variable name later in the same function :)

Does any of you know of a FP Language that implements something similar to this? Is it even a reasonable requirement from FP or am I missing something?

Comment: Just a note: zeroing of buffers is both rare and hard (in the sense that, if you aren't very careful, the compiler will optimize out your attempt to do so). While it's certainly preferable, it's unlikely to be the weak link in a cryptographic system, and you may want to focus your effort on other areas which are much more likely to improve security. Avoiding the leakage of keys in crash dumps can usually be achieved by just turning off crash dumps, or at least storing them somewhere an unauthorized user can't access (noting that a privileged user can read them out of the process directly).

Comment: @CBHacking Thanks. You probably know there are also other cases that make this best practice important. For example, when several threads belonging to different users share the same memory. So it is difficult to categorize it as the weakest link or not. It is a best practice that is implemented as a preventative measure. How weak it makes the system depends on other factors..

Comment: "several threads belonging to different users share the same memory" I'm really curious what you mean by this, actually. Every case I can think of, this either doesn't require zeroing the memory, or is inherently insecure even with zeroing. Shared memory is common, for example as an IPC mechanism, and it might cross a trust boundary, but in that case it's a _communication channel_; nothing goes into it unless it's intended to be viewed by the other party/parties. You can't ever reliably keep something secret if you put it into memory somebody else can read, even if you erase it later.

Comment: @CBHacking The simplest example is a web server that returns data to different clients. If the memory with senstivie data is freed and reallocated it's not always guaranteed to be initialized or zeroized, so data leakage can occur.

Comment: That depends on the runtime and nobody in their right mind writes webservers in memory-unsafe languages anymore, but fair enough. At least C - or rather, inline assembly in C - lets you work around the compiler-optimization problem; most high-level languages just straight up don't support secure zeroization unless the runtime provides a function that was written in assembly to do it.

Comment: @CBHacking I had a half-baked idea once that in a memory-managed language you should at least be able to have a certain data type that gets zeroized whenever the garbage collector gets to it, so that you're at least guaranteed "eventual" zeroization. It's been a very long time since I thought about this stuff (as you can see from the date of the OP) but I remember thinking that this is even more relevant to FP languages where you usually are not allowed to reassign a value to variables...